# Does the whole .NET assembly get loaded in memory or just the parts used?

Tags: .net, assemblies

If I have a 15M .NET assembly and a program calls a method in it, does the whole assembly get loaded into memory and use 15M or a lot less? (assuming the assembly is not allocating any memory during runtime)

Comment: btw, this link contains many useful information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, all assembly gets loaded into current AppDomain;

Also, check this link for more information on subject: [Why isn't there an Assembly.Unload method?](http://blogs.msdn.com/jasonz/archive/2004/05/31/145105.aspx)

Comment: That link is quite old. Pre 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? If we capture a process dump (full memory dump) of your program, we can extract all the assemblies from that dump. Is that a sign that all assemblies are actually loaded into memory?